# git submodule specify version

Tags: git

I have git submodule. 
I have `.gitmodules` file.

```
[submodule "templates-ui/src/main/webapp/js/app/ui"]
    path = templates-ui/src/main/webapp/js/app/ui
    url = git@github.com:xxx/ui-core.git
```

I did `init` and `update`.

But how to specify the version of the submodule? For example I may have version of of `ui-core` as `2.3.2` or `2.3.3`.

Comment: A submodule is just a repository within another repository.  Let me ask you how would you name any plain vanilla Git repo according to version?

Comment: Well for every version there is specific commit like `increased build version` where one file is modify...But well that's the question actually...Hm Hm. I can just to point to a specific commit

Comment: You _could_ use a version file, but in practice you could look at the history of the parent repo to see the various versions which the submodule has had.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

git tracks submodules as ordinary objects.
this means, that once you added the submodule, the exact state (e.g. revision) of the submodule is stored in the parent module as well.

so do:

```
cd submodule
git checkout v2.3.2
cd -
git commit . -m "use submodule v2.3.2"
```

as side-effect of the way githandles submodules is, that you cannot have a "live" submodule¹ (where you always track the HEAD of a master branch) - a submodule is really always in a *detached* state.

¹ well you can; nobody keeps you from tracking master/HEAD in the submodule by manually `pull`ing within the submodule; but the parent module will always reference a specific commitish.